# Background Page JS code logs differently in popup console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am experiencing a really bizarre bug.

In my background.js file I have a function that closes tabs like so

```
closeTabs = function(tabIds,category){
    for(var i=0; i<tabIds.length;i++){
        var url = findTabById(tabIds[i]).url;
        console.log(url);
        reservedUrls.push(url);
    }
    console.log(arrToString(reservedUrls));
    if(tabIds.length>0){
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabIds,function(){
        });
    }
}
```

This function is called from my browser action.

I then have an event listener for the remove tab event.

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId){
    console.log('removed');
    var removedUrl = findTabById(tabId).url;
    console.log(removedUrl);
    console.log(arrToString(reservedUrls));
    var index = reservedUrls.indexOf(removedUrl);
    if(index>-1){
        console.log('in here');
        reservedUrls.splice(index,1);
    } else {
        var category = findCategoryById(tabId);
        if(category){
            for(var i=0;i<currentTabs[category];i++){
                if(currentTabs[category][i].id==tabId){
                    currentTabs[category].splice(i,1);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for(var i=0;i<ungrouped.length;i++){
                if(ungrouped[i].id==tabId){
                    ungrouped.splice(i,1);
                }
            }
        }
        console.log('sending message');
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'removed',tabId:tabId});
    }
    console.log(currentTabs);
});
```

When tabs are closed by the first function, I place them in reservedUrls, so that the logic acts differently. When I look at the console of the background page, it enters the if statement like it should. However, in the console of the popup, it logs that it navigated into the else statement.

Has anyone every experience this disparity. If so, what are the typical causes?

Answer (score 0):

You remove tab script is executed in own context, it does not mean it removes tabs synchronously. So your listener gets the event once tab is really removed from the system. You could check this with a page that prevents tab from closing form unload event